# Users: List A to Z, for Users

Tags: users

I would like to create a list of all the alphabets that represent each user in my site.

Example:

```
A -> Link that shows list of all users whose **nickname** starting with letter "A"
B -> ...starting with letter "B"
C -> ...starting with letter "C"
D -> ...starting with letter "D"
E -> ...starting with letter "E"
F -> ...starting with letter "F"
.
.
Z -> ...starting with letter "Z"
```

I would like to list every alphabet regardless of if there is or isn't a user for it. But would also to know how to only show alphabets with users. Im not sure exactly which method I'll end up using, but I just want to have the option.

Ive searched online but couldnt find anything for my particular situation.

Id appreciate any help with this. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's the [WP_User_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User_Query) for that:

```
/**
 * List all Users
 * Use as: Template Tag
 * 
 * @uses WP_User_Query
 * @return (array) List of user objects
 */
wpse35713_get_users_list()
{
    $query = new WP_User_Query( array(
         'order'    => 'ASC'
        ,'orderby'  => 'login'
    ) );
    $users = $query->get_results();

    $html  = "<ul><li>";
    foreach ( $users as $user )
    {
        $html .= "</li><li>{$user}";
    }
    $html .= "</li><ul>";

    return $html;
}
```